# Stripe CLI webhook not invoked when card declined

Tags: javascript, django, stripe-payments

I am using the stripe CLI to test webhooks in my django application. When a payment goes through, the webhook records this and seems to work perfectly fine. However, whenever I am using one of the stripe test cards that get declined (such as: 4000000000009987), its as if the webhook never gets called, even though stripe tells me the error that the card was declined. It's as if the webhook never even gets called from stripe when a payment fails. What am I missing?

my webhook in python

```
@require_POST
@csrf_exempt
def webhook_received(request):
    stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
    endpoint_secret = settings.STRIPE_ENDPOINT_SECRET
    payload = request.body
    sig_header = request.META['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE']
    event = None

    try:
        event = stripe.Webhook.construct_event(
        payload, sig_header, endpoint_secret
        )
    except ValueError as e:
        # Invalid payload
        return HttpResponse(status=400)
    except stripe.error.SignatureVerificationError as e:
        # Invalid signature
        return HttpResponse(status=400)

    print('THE EVENT: ', event)
    print('THE EVENT TYPE: ', event.type)
    # Handle the event
    if event.type == 'payment_intent.succeeded':
        payment_intent = event.data.object # contains a stripe.PaymentIntent
        # Then define and call a method to handle the successful payment intent.
        # handle_payment_intent_succeeded(payment_intent)
    elif event.type == 'payment_method.attached':
        payment_method = event.data.object # contains a stripe.PaymentMethod
        # Then define and call a method to handle the successful attachment of a PaymentMethod.
        # handle_payment_method_attached(payment_method)
    elif event.type == 'checkout.session.completed':
        pass
    elif event.type == 'invoice.paid':
        # Used to provision services after the trial has ended.
        # The status of the invoice will show up as paid. Store the status in your
        # database to reference when a user accesses your service to avoid hitting rate
        # limits.

        print('invoice.paid')
        print(event.data)

        database_plan = Plan.objects.values('plan_short', 'stripe_plan_id')

        confirmed_plan = event.data['object']['lines']['data'][0]['plan']['product']
        print('PLAN CONFIRMED: ', confirmed_plan)

        for plan in database_plan:
            if plan["stripe_plan_id"] == confirmed_plan:
                print("The plan is: " + plan["plan_short"])
                new_plan = plan["plan_short"]

        user_instance = Account.objects.get(
            email=event.data['object']['customer_email'])

        # check if user already has new plan, if not, we are adding it here
        if user_instance.plan != new_plan:
            row_to_change = Account.objects.get(
                email=event.data['object']['customer_email'])
            setattr(row_to_change, 'plan', new_plan)
            row_to_change.save()

            plan_translations = {"S": "Staff", "A": "Admin"}

            ...

            # creating stripe customer in local database
            if StripeCustomer.objects.filter(user=user_instance).exists():
                print('stripe user already here')
                pass
            else:
                StripeCustomer.objects.create(
                    user=user_instance,
                    stripeCustomerId=event.data['object']['customer'],
                    stripeSubscriptionId=event.data['object']['subscription'],
                    stripeCurrentProductId=confirmed_plan,
                )
                print('added a new stripe user')
        else:
            pass
    elif event.type == 'invoice.payment_failed':
        # If the payment fails or the customer does not have a valid payment method,
        # an invoice.payment_failed event is sent, the subscription becomes past_due.
        # Use this webhook to notify your user that their payment has
        # failed and to retrieve new card details.
        print('invoice.payment_failed')
        print(event.data)

    elif event.type == 'customer.subscription.deleted':
        # handle subscription cancelled automatically based
        # upon your subscription settings. Or if the user cancels it.
        print('customer.subscription.deleted')
        print(event.data)
    else:
        print('Unhandled event type {}'.format(event.type))

    return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

my create_subscription in python

```
@csrf_exempt
def createSubscription(request):

    data1 = json.load(request)
    data = data1['customerId']
    try:
        # Attach the payment method to the customer
        stripe.PaymentMethod.attach(
            data['paymentMethodId'],
            customer=data['customerId'],
        )
        # Set the default payment method on the customer
        stripe.Customer.modify(
            data['customerId'],
            invoice_settings={
                'default_payment_method': data['paymentMethodId'],
            },
        )

        # Create the subscription
        subscription = stripe.Subscription.create(
            customer=data['customerId'],
            items=[
                {
                    'price': data['priceId']
                }
            ],
            expand=['latest_invoice.payment_intent'],
        )
        print('subscription: ', subscription)
        return JsonResponse(subscription)
    except Exception as e:
        result = {}
        # error = {'message': str(e)}
        result['error'] = {'message': str(e).split(":",1)[1]+' Please try again with a different card.' }
        return JsonResponse(result)
```

my create_payment_method in JS

```
function createPaymentMethod(cardElement, customerId, priceId) {
  return stripe
    .createPaymentMethod({
      type: 'card',
      card: cardElement,
    })
    .then((result) => {
      if (result.error) {
        displayError(result);
      } else {
        createSubscription({
          customerId: customerId,
          paymentMethodId: result.paymentMethod.id,
          priceId: priceId,
        });
      }
    });
}
```

my create_subscription in JS:

```
function createSubscription(customerId, paymentMethodId, priceId) {
  return (
    fetch('/payments/create-subscription/', {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        customerId: customerId,
        paymentMethodId: paymentMethodId,
        priceId: priceId,
      }),
    })
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      // If the card is declined, display an error to the user.
      .then((result) => {
        if (result.error) {
          // The card had an error when trying to attach it to a customer.
          throw result;
        }
        return result;
      })
      // Normalize the result to contain the object returned by Stripe.
      // Add the additional details we need.
      .then((result) => {
        return {
          paymentMethodId: paymentMethodId,
          priceId: priceId,
          subscription: result,
        };
      })
      // Some payment methods require a customer to be on session
      // to complete the payment process. Check the status of the
      // payment intent to handle these actions.
      .then(handlePaymentThatRequiresCustomerAction)
      // No more actions required. Provision your service for the user.
      .then(onSubscriptionComplete)
      .catch((error) => {
        // An error has happened. Display the failure to the user here.
        // We utilize the HTML element we created.
        console.log('createSubscription wrong code')
        displayError(error);
      })
  );
}
```

my displayError in JS:

```
function displayError(event) {
    //changeLoadingStatePrices(false);
    let displayError = document.getElementById('card-element-errors');
    if (event.error) {
      displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
    } else {
      displayError.textContent = '';
    }
}
```

Do you know why the webhook is only recording successful events?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I believe you don't get Events/Webhooks for declines that happen on-session like that(i.e the ones coming from calling `stripe.Subscription.create` ). You don't need the event because you can catch the exception directly in your synchronous code and handle it there(which your code does).

Comment: @karllekko     thanks a lot for your response, that makes sense. How do I test for such declined cards then tho? (I am using metered billing, so the actual charge happens at the end of the month) I can't add a 'declined card' to any stripe customer for above reasons...

Comment: you can use the 4000000000000341 card for that ! https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards-responses